# manifest.json 404 not found when trying to run server that's just established

Tags: node.js, reactjs, manifest

I am getting started with a server, following steps from [here](https://fullstackopen.com/en/part2/getting_data_from_server#npm).

When running server however, I am getting the error :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.

I have tried installing reinstalling server packages, renaming files, changing url, switching locations.